# Invalid path: 'null.name'

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Пытаюсь сделать выборку из бд согласно заданным параметрам. И получаю такую ошибку:

```
Invalid path: 'null.name' [select cities FROM model.pojo.Country WHERE Country.name=Ливия]
```

Вот pojo классы:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CITY")
public class City implements Comparable<City>, Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequnce_id_generator_city")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequnce_id_generator_city", sequenceName = "SEQ_FOR_CITY_ID")
@Column (name="ID")
private int id;
@Column (name="NAME")
private String name;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Hotel.class, mappedBy="city")
private Set<Hotel> hotels = new HashSet();
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY", nullable=false)
private Country country;
```

И второй:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequnce_id_generator_country")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequnce_id_generator_country", sequenceName = "SEQ_FOR_COUNTRY_ID")
@Column (name="ID")
private int id;
@Column (name="NAME")
private String name;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=City.class, mappedBy="country")
private Set<City> cities= new HashSet();
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Hotel.class, mappedBy="country")
private Set<Hotel> hotels= new HashSet();
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="COUNTRIES_TOUR_OPERATORS",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="TOUR_OPERATOR_ID"))
private Set<Operator> operators= new HashSet();
```

Вот запрос:

```
public static List<City> getAllCities(String name) {
List<City> list = null;
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
try{
    Session session = GenericDAOHibernateImpl.getSession();
    String hql = "select cities FROM Country WHERE Country.name="+name;
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    list = query.list();
}
```

Подозреваю проблему в запросе. Только не могу понять где...

Comment: Ваш пример не работает из-за, что вы добавляли `name` без кавычек как того требует синтаксис `SQL`.  Но гораздо более лучший способ передавать параметры через  специальную конструкцию, как указал Sergey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String hql = "from Country c where c.name = :name";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
  .setString("name", name)
  .list();
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можете подсказать какую то литературу по формированию hql запросов. Желательно на русском

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Не может быть ничего лучше [официальной документации](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql).

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо!!!!!